# Creation of Anaconda launcher

Tags: gnome, launcher, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 3 but in order to run the Anaconda Navigator each time i have to use the terminal by typing

source anaconda3/bin/activate ~/anaconda3/

and then

anaconda-navigator

Is there a way to create a launcher in the start menu? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? Could I put a code like "source anaconda3/bin/activate ~/anaconda3/" ?!?

Comment: Yes, you could create that launcher and make the command it runs be the two you listed.

Comment: i have tried..but the new launcher tells me "Failed to execute child process "source" (No such file or directory)"

Comment: You should make a script and then direct the command to run that script. Don't put the raw command in there. So just put the two commands in a file with no extension and make it executable with `chmod +x filename` and then point to it in the launcher by just writing the path for it.